# Changing the angle of rotation using a coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have a game object bg whose rotation in the z-axis can be controlled using the keys in the update method. I'm calculating the position of another object based on the rotation angle.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InputController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _currentTargetPos;
    private float _targetRotationOffset = 0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _target;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _testFlag; // change in editor

    void Start()
    {
        _currentTargetPos = _target.localPosition;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float rotationAngle = 0;

        float currentRotation = bg.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z /* For the first version + _targetRotationOffset */;

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(currentRotation, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f));

        VVector3 rotatedVector = rotation * (_currentTargetPos - bg.transform.position);
        Vector3 rotatedPoint = rotatedVector + bg.transform.position;
        _target.localPosition = rotatedPoint;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            bg.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, currentRotation - 60f * Time.deltaTime);
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            bg.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, currentRotation + 60f * Time.deltaTime);

        if (_testFlag)
        {
            StartCoroutine(TestRotate());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TestRotate()
    {
        // FIRST VERSION

        /* float startRotation = bg.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
        float timer = 0f;
        float rotationDuration = 2f; 

        while (timer < rotationDuration)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            float t = Mathf.Clamp01(timer / rotationDuration);
            float currentRotation = Mathf.LerpAngle(startRotation, 20f, t);
            _targetRotationOffset = currentRotation;

            yield return null;
        }

        _testFlag = false;*/



        // SECOND VERSION

        /* Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(20f, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f));

         Vector3 rotatedVector = rotation * (_currentTargetPos - bg.transform.position);
         Vector3 rotatedPoint = rotatedVector + bg.transform.position;

         while (true)
         {
             _target.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(_target.localPosition,
                         rotatedPoint, 0.2f * Time.deltaTime);

             if (Vector3.Distance(_target.localPosition, rotatedPoint) <= 20f)
             {
                 _currentTargetPos = _target.localPosition;
                 Debug.Log("Done");
                 _testFlag = false;

                 yield break;
             }

             _currentTargetPos = _target.localPosition;

             yield return null;
         }*/
    }
}
```

I want to make it possible to specify in another method the angle for the rotation of the bg object by a certain number of degrees, and this rotation was taken into account when changing the position of the bg in the update.
In simple terms, I want to achieve independent rotation of the bg object using the keys and by calling another method.

I'm trying to create a coroutine in which I make changes to the angle. The angle changes, but the rotation of the bg object using the arrows does not work correctly.

I tried to store the angle of rotation in a separate variable and add to  bg.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z and change _currentTargetPos in the coroutine, but the rotation of bg still does not work correctly.

It seems that the solution is somewhere nearby, but I have not been able to figure out where for a couple of days.

How can I change the rotation angle in another method with this implementation of the rotation and position change in the update?

UPD: added class code

Comment: Could you post a complete code snippet? Currently it is really hard to tell what are fields and what methods and what is called exactly how and when ...

Comment: Updated information

Comment: Your coroutine creates some local variables that seem not be used by anything else .. the only field that is assigned is `_targetRotationOffset` which is not used by anything.. a bit confused what exactly you are trying to achieve tbh

Comment: I commented out the code, just to show where what I tried to use.
For the first version, I added _targetRotationOffset in this line: float currentRotation = bg.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z + _targetRotationOffset; in the update method. And in the coroutine I got it through: _targetRotationOffset = currentRotation;

For the second version, I changed _currentTargetPos and assigned it a new value here: _currentTargetPos = _target.localPosition; Using this variable in the update code, the vector is calculated:
Vector3 rotatedVector = rotation * (_currentTargetPos - bg.transform.position);

Comment: So just trying to understand again what you actually trying to achieve ... you want to control the `bg.rotation` using the arrow keys as well as having another method (in your example a Coroutine - does it have to be one?) influence the same `bg.rotation` as well, is this about right? Follow-up question: Should both happen at the same time -> additive rotation for both? Or should one overrule the other?

Comment: Yes, I use the arrows to rotate the bg. I want to be able to also influence the rotation from other methods, such as when a flag (_testFlag) fires. When the flag is triggered, smoothly rotate the background, and at this time, you can rotate it with the keys, for example, in the opposite direction. I thought it would be possible to use a coroutine. And one coroutine would be enough to call it periodically.

Comment: The rotation in the coroutine, as planned, should only affect the calculation of the _target position, but for now I'm trying to figure out how to at least influence the bg rotation. Yes, rotation must occur simultaneously.

Comment: currently you start a new Coroutine each and every frame while the condition is true ... that's why I think you wouldn't even need a Coroutine at all but simple check the flag in Update and handle he case accordingly directly ...

Comment: I change the flag in the editor. Specified in the code: private bool _testFlag; // change in editor

Comment: I want to understand the principle itself, in which you can change the rotation and position simultaneously with the keyboard buttons and in another method.

Answer (score 0):

To add an independent change in the rotation angle, I simply added another variable _rotationOffset, the value of which I change in another method through the coroutine.

To add an independent change in the rotation angle, I simply added another variable and added _rotationOffset to it, the value of which I change in another method through the coroutine.

Thus, one value is calculated for rotation bg, and another value is calculated for the position _target, with an offset.

```
float currentRotationOffset = bg.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z + _rotationOffset;    
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(currentRotationOffset, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f));
```